# Azure Service Fabric change ip

Tags: azure, vpn, http-proxy, openvpn, azure-service-fabric

I'm having a solution in the Azure Service Fabric, we are gathering a lot of information from various sources.

I'm facing a very known issue : some of the source we connect to start to block the IP. So I'm looking for a way to use some VPN service like hidemyass.com or anything like that.

My problem is all the VPN providers provide a client you must install on your machine, as you well know it is impossible for me to install the client on my 56 Servers.

Does anyone knows for a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Azure Service Fabric is running on "Azure Virtual Machine Scale Sets" you should try to automate the installation. Azure Virtual Machines have a concept called "Virtual Machine Extensions". Software like the "Azure Diagnostics Agent" are automatically installed on each of your nodes through this mechanism.

Since the program you want to install will most likely not be available directly as a Virtual Machine Extension, you could use [Azure Automation DSC](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/automation-dsc-overview/) (Desired State Configuration) to install additional software on your nodes.

DSC needs an agent on your virtual machines, which is available as a Virtual Machine Extension. There is an [ARM-based template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-automation-dsc) that shows how you can integrate the extension into a Virtual Machine Scale Set. You can include this extension in your Service Fabric ARM template and re-deploy it to have the extension installed on each of your nodes.

After this, you could use the [Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/packageresource) feature of DSC to install your software.

However, be aware that creating this solution might require a considerable amount of time. PowerShell DSC is a very powerful system that, once installed, gives you many more possibilities in terms of server management.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you